# Load events dynamically on w3widgets responsive calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, calendar

I am currently using w3widgets' responsive calendar plugin. I have been able to load events on load using AJAX to fetch the dates and calling the plugin and passing the event dates as such

```js
//AJAX call to fetch and store event dates in variable eventList and then...

$(".responsive-calendar").responsiveCalendar({
  events: eventList
});
```

However, I have a button to fetch more events. I am able to fetch the new dates and store in a variable as above but unable to populate them on the calendar. Any ideas on how 'm supposed to achieve this?

Comment: did you get a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, after a lot of failed efforts, contacted the maker of the W3widgets.

**and here is the solution:**

```
$(".responsive-calendar").responsiveCalendar({

        time: TodaysDate,

        onMonthChange: function () {
            dates = GetEventsForTheMonth(this.currentMonth + 1, this.currentYear)
            this.editDays(JSON.parse(dates))
        },

        events: JSON.parse(dates)

    });
```

I have declared the variable `dates` globally.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var res = $(".responsive-calendar").responsiveCalendar({
  events: eventList
});

/*fetch more 'newEvents' events*/
res.events = newEvents;
```

Comment: I tried this, it adds the new events to the object but does not update/populate the calendar with the new events :(